# Topologists glueing, cutting and so on. When is this rigorous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I often see that things in topology are explained very non-rigorously recently.
Thereby I mean that it is said that we can cut something and glue something together and so on in order to identify two objects. Sure, in general one would need to write down a map, but this is often very very cumbersome. Therefore, I understand that people tend to illustrate things. Despite, we never talked about actual does and dont's and I would like to understand the following. How do I know that I am allowed to cut something or glue something together? Where do I need to pay attention?

Comment: Do you know about quotient topologies and quotient maps?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I feel as they are rarely explicitely included in these kind of argumentations.

Comment: You are right, the required quotient maps are rarely made explicit. Nonetheless, quotient maps and quotient topologies are, almost always, the rigorous concept that underlies cutting and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such rule (your intuition, gained from lots of examples, will tell it, if you want to gain some intuition then you should look at Jänich's topology), and apart from that these intuitive arguments are almost always used only for examples, and not for the theory itself. And these can usually be made rigorous: e.g. let us prove that the circle $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $I/\partial I$ ($I=[0,1]$ the unit interval), the space obtained from $I$ by identifying the endpoints: define the surjective map $I\rightarrow S^1$ by $x\mapsto\exp(2\pi ix)$; since this respects the equivalence relation on $I$ from which $I/\partial I$ is obtained, we get an induced surjection $I/\partial I\rightarrow S^1$, which is injective (because our first map is injective apart from the endpoints). Now $I/\partial I$ is compact and $S^1$ is Hausdorff, hence this map is a homeomorphism. Similar arguments work for surfaces; this is done in great detail in Munkres' topology.